# PyPlot error "X and Y must be same size", everything I've found online isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to create a Linear Regression model in Scikit-Learn. Although I've encountered a problem. It's saying that x and y are not the same size. I am using googles "california housing" dataset. Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/california_housing_train.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 1/3)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()

lr.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = lr.predict(x_test)

plt.scatter(x_train, y_train, color = "red")
plt.plot(x_train, lr.predict(x_train), color = "green")
plt.title("Income vs Home Value (Training set)")
plt.xlabel("Income")
plt.ylabel("Home Value")
plt.show()

plt.scatter(x_test, y_test, color = "red")
plt.plot(x_train, lr.predict(x_train), color = "green")
plt.title("Income vs Home Value (Testing set)")
plt.xlabel("Income")
plt.ylabel("Home value")
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-95095200e54b> in <module>()
     18 y_pred = lr.predict(x_test)
     19 
---> 20 plt.scatter(x_train[0], y_train[:], color = "red")
     21 plt.plot(x_train, lr.predict(x_train), color = "green")
     22 plt.title("Income vs Home Value (Training set)")

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4389         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   4390         if x.size != y.size:
-> 4391             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   4392 
   4393         if s is None:

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

I have no idea why. I've tried everything on other posts. According to what I've found on other posts, it's because one(x or y) is 2d and one is 1d. Although the "fixes" aren't working.

Comment: I don't see this line in your code above. ` plt.scatter(x_train[0], y_train[:], color = "red")`

Comment: I tried that and it did not work, it still said the same error. I was just trying to give the plain code without all my failed attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the dimensions of your x & y variables:

```
[ins] In [34]: x.shape                                                                                                                     
Out[34]: (17000, 7)

[ins] In [35]: y.shape                                                                                                                     
Out[35]: (17000, 8)
```

The y variable should be the target variable, the home price:

```
y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values
```

Your x-variable definition leaves out the median_income, which is what you are trying to plot, so here is an x matrix that includes the income variable:

```
x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
```

With y defined as above it is now 1-dimensional; the x matrix has 8 variables in it, the last of which (index 7) is median_income. To plot it:

```
plt.scatter(x_train[:,7], y_train, color = "red")
```